# Best way to "proxy" resource server-side?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to proxy only the web-site part of `streamable.com` (because access to its web front end is blocked here) and my current implementation pretty straightforward:

```php
 <body>
 <?php
 $html = file_get_contents('https://streamable.com/' . $_GET['path']);
 echo $html;
 ?> 
 </body>
```

I just output fetched HTML. This way I can get access to webfront and all requests to CDN are native i.e. direct connection. While this works fine I was curious if there are some way to improve upon it? My only guess so far is probably some caching, but I'm not sure what type and how. So I guess essentially my question is - what kind of simple built-on caching solution I can implement?

Running Apache on free Googiehost if that matters.